# send command from windows java application(server application) to android software for taking picture

Tags: android

I want send command from java windows application(we are called to this java application , server) to android softwae for taking picture and save in sc card? how i can do it? any body can help me?
I used androrat software but id doesn't work ....
who can help me? 
thanks a lot my friends!!!!!!

```
if ((command == Protocol.GET_PICTURE)) {
            System.out.println("1");
            if ( !channelHandlerMap.get(imei).registerListener(channel, new RawPacket()))//this line has error...........!!1
                System.out.println("2");
            gui.logErrTxt("ERROR: channel " + channel + " is already in use!");
            System.out.println("3");
            channelHandlerMap.get(imei).registerHandler(channel, new PictureHandler(channel, imei, gui));
            System.out.println("4");
            gui.savePictureChannel(imei, channel);
            System.out.println("5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your device on gcm server and store information on you app server. Then when you wish to trigger OpenCamera operation send push to this device which was stored on you server. This process is a bit complicated but once understood its very easy.

Please Refer:

[GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

[GCM Tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/)

Comment: dear friend , i mean that  , i wans send command to android software form windows java application( server) , do u work with androrat? this is androrat but my server is windows application